# Why Commit using VSCode IDE mess the Commit's Author info?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, ide, commit

If I type:

```
git config --list
```

here's the list of my configs:

```
user.name=markzzz
user.email=markzzz@mymail.com
user.name=markzzz
user.email=markzzz@mymail.com
```

Once I do the first commit using `VSCode IDE` (1.37.1, on Windows), and than I see the commit:

```
git log origin/master..master
```

Damn, that's not the author:

```
$ git log origin/master..master
commit d9a47958dasafasf0219888b251e324528de0b5f (HEAD -> master)
Author: paul <paul@anothermail.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 29 14:20:34 2019 +0200

    test
```

Why? 
Before to set the correct Author, I first need to do this:

```
git config user.name "markzzz"
git config user.email "markzzz@mymail.com"
```

Than it works using IDE. Its annoying, and sometimes I forgot it.

Where are those "overwritten" infos? It do this only using VSCode IDE: if I do `git commit -m "test"` using the bash, it works as expected.

Comment: Maybe you have a different global configuration? Check `git config --global --list`.

Comment: @kowsky it prints correctly `user.name=markzzz
user.email=markzzz@mymail.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why does VSCode do this?

It doesn't.  At least, it's not supposed to, and I've never seen it happen.

Something must be wrong.

#### How can one debug this?

First, in the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), run "Git: Show Git Output".  Keep that window open when you perform a commit and watch its output.  Note that what you see in that output is every command that is run, along with its *stderr* output, but not stdout.

Second, try running `git commit` from a Terminal inside VSCode: Terminal → New Terminal.  See if that reproduces the problem.  Try the `git config` commands from there, etc.

Third, if none of that reveals the problem, try writing your own `git` wrapper script and set the `git.path` setting (`settings.json`, or File → Preferences → Settings → Git) to point at it.  Have the wrapper script log everything it does.

Comment: As I said, git commit from terminal commit it correctly. Its the IDE that ruin the commit.

Comment: Did you try the Terminal that is inside VSCode?  It seemed to me that by "if I do `git commit -m "test"` using the bash, it works as expected", you meant running `bash` *outside* of VSCode.

Comment: No, of couse I'm running the bash inside VSCode, on Terminal. Here's the bash I'm using right now: `C:/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe`

Comment: Yes! I'm on Windows, and VS Code use Git Extension by default, which got those author info.

Answer (score 1):

You should try below

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.email "youremail@domain.com"
```

Reference https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email

Comment: I already did it. As you can see, `git config --list` return those data (and `system` data).

Comment: try with --global, it will help you.

Comment: ? as I said, I already did it! `git config --global --list` print the same, as for `git config --system --list`

Comment: It's no use setting and resetting the global config entry since it looks like it's overridden by something else. Check `git config --list --local` also.

Comment: @RomainValeri `git config --list --local` does print nothing about name and/or mail. There aren't those `paul` information

Comment: `echo $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME $GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL $GIT_COMMITTER_NAME $GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` ???

Comment: @phd: print nothing

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be that some [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) is modifying commits being made.

Namely, check `.git/hooks/` for a `pre-commit` (not the .sample) file, and if present, look what it does. Just rename it or move it out of /hooks to permanently invalidate it.

A simple test (to rule this out if it's not the case) would be to try

```
git commit -n -m "test"
```

since `-n` temporarily invalidates these hooks.

Comment: Uhm... doing `git commit -m "test"` seems to works, so it's not hooks :O It seems that if I use the Git from vscode, here's the problem (I do commit from the GUI)

Comment: Ok, so the IDE seems to be the culprit. We're making progress here :-)

Comment: The fact is that I don't have any settings on the IDE. Not sure where it pick those informations :O